# Hot to get the value of the same period last year in the Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

There is a row group in .rdl file(paginated report) which calculates some aggregate function for a certain period. So grouping is performed by this period. Dataset also returns data for the same period but 1 year ago.

How can I add some column to the right side of the report which will perform the same aggregate function but for the same period 1 year ago? Which function should I use for it? So I should see in the row for this month(period) the aggregate value of this month and the month 1 year ago. Is there CTE functions in report builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this formula for a cell value was helpful:
=Previous(Sum(Fields!somefield.Value), "Year_Group_Name")